# File Exists function in USQL

Tags: azure, u-sql

I am doing a simple test in USQL to check if a file exists and then perform Merge operations based on that. However, I cannot seem to get this right. Can you please help me with this and let me know where am I going wrong.

```
DECLARE @InputFile1 string = "/MergeTest/FINAL/Check1.csv";
DECLARE @InputFile2 string = "/MergeTest/STAGING/Test-{*}.json";                                                                         
DECLARE @OutputFile1 string = "/MergeTest/FINAL/Check1.csv";

IF (FILE.EXISTS(@InputFile1))
THEN
@Final = EXTRACT [ID] int,
                 [Name] string,
                 [City] string,
                 [Country] string
FROM @InputFile1
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);
END;

@Delta = EXTRACT [ID] int,
                 [Name] string,
                 [City] string,
                 [Country] string
FROM @InputFile2
USING new JsonExtractor("$.DEP[*]");
```

The below code does not work in the IF condition . I get the error : @FileExists is already declared as a scalar variable. If this is a wrong way to implement this, what would be the correct approach?

```
@FileExists = SELECT (FILE.EXISTS(@InputFile1)) AS exists_good FROM (VALUES (1)) AS T(dummy);

IF ####@FileExists THEN
    @result =   SELECT * FROM @Delta
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * FROM Final AS T1
                ANTISEMIJOIN (SELECT * FROM @Delta) AS T2
                ON T1.[ID] == T2.[ID];
ELSE
    @result =   SELECT * FROM @Delta;
END;

OUTPUT @result   
TO @OutputFile1
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader:true);
```

Thanks,
Sunitha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write this instead:

```
IF FILE.EXISTS(@InputFile1) THEN ...
```

When you assign to this with `SELECT` this is basically a rowset and cannot be treated like a scalar variable.

I also note in your example that `@inputFile1` and `@outputFile1` have the same filename.  I am sure this will cause problems.  Make sure they are different in your real example.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  That was something I missed out. It works all good now.. `IF FILE.EXISTS(@InputFile1) THEN
 @result =  SELECT * FROM @Delta
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM @Final AS T1
    ANTISEMIJOIN (SELECT * FROM @Delta) AS T2
    ON T1.[MANDT] == T2.[MANDT] AND T1.[KUNNR] == T2.[KUNNR];
ELSE
 @result =  SELECT * FROM @Delta;`

Comment: Also, Is there any particular reason my `inputFile1` and my `outputFile1` should be two different ones?  It still works.

Comment: It may work now but can you guarantee that will always be the case?  I think logically it makes me a bit nervous (exactly what transaction semantics are in play here?)) plus you would also lose your audit trail ie once you have run your job, you no longer know your starting point (input1) so this could make debugging difficult.  For that reason alone I would set them to different files.  Storage is cheap right : )